# How to Set Pyspark Dataframe Headers to another Row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# +----+------+---------+
# |col1| col2 |  col3   |
# +----+------+---------+
# |  id| name |    val  |
# |  1 |  a01 |    X    |
# |  2 |  a02 |    Y    |
# +---+-------+---------+
```

I need to create a new dataframe from it, using row[1] as the new column headers and ignoring or dropping the col1, col2, etc. row. The new table should look like this:

```
# +----+------+---------+
# | id | name |   val   |
# +----+------+---------+
# |  1 |  a01 |    X    |
# |  2 |  a02 |    Y    |
# +---+-------+---------+
```

The columns can be variable, so I can't use the names to set them explicitly in the new dataframe. This is not using pandas df's.

Comment: What is the original source for first DF? Why don't you create the "second" in just one step?

Comment: The source is from a data source in an AWS Glue ETL workflow. The original source is from a csv file in S3, the funky column header names are added during the workflow. The call to get the df looks like this: glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(...) then I call datasource0.toDF() to get the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried usingread csv? `sqlContext.read.format('csv').option('header', True).load(<S3 path>)`

Comment: The glue job has to extract the data with that exact command to pull it from a glue data source, it's not just pulling it from S3, it's reading from a provided source. There's a way to do it with pandas: df.columns = df.iloc[1] then df.reindex(df.index.drop(1))   - the goal would be to replicate something like this, but natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming that there is only one row with *`id` in col1*, *`name` in col2* and *`val` in col3***, you can use the following logic (commented for clarity and explanation)

```
#select the row with the header name 
header = df.filter((df['col1'] == 'id') & (df['col2'] == 'name') & (df['col3'] == 'val'))

#selecting the rest of the rows except the first one 
restDF = df.subtract(header)

#converting the header row into Row 
headerColumn = header.first()

#looping columns for renaming 
for column in restDF.columns:
    restDF = restDF.withColumnRenamed(column, headerColumn[column])

restDF.show(truncate=False)
```

this should give you

```
+---+----+---+
|id |name|val|
+---+----+---+
|1  |a01 |X  |
|2  |a02 |Y  |
+---+----+---+
```

But the best option would be read it *with header option set to true* while reading the *dataframe* using *sqlContext* from source

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this? **header=True**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("TSCAINV_062020.csv",header=True)
```

Pyspark sets the column names as _c0, _c1, _c2 if the header is not set to True  and it pushes the column down by one row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sai Kiran!
The `header=True` works for me:

`df = spark.read.csv("TSCAINV_062020.csv",header=True)`