# How can I read headers with .createDataFrame()?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading some data from a Google API. The data being returned looks like so:

```
print(data)
[['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['543', '15197', '49877729'], ['9288', '285985', '29762969'], ['13709', '28146', '94968440'], ['1', '98480', '154381985'], ['586', '137709', '74962864'] ...]
```

The first row is the header names. I then convert the above to a Spark df like so:

```
spark_df = (
  spark
  .createDataFrame(data, header=True)
)
```

Which gives this error:

> TypeError: createDataFrame() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

How can I solve this? I looked at the accepted answer here [How to Set Pyspark Dataframe Headers to another Row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593337/how-to-set-pyspark-dataframe-headers-to-another-row) but surely a loop can be avoided for this? The second answer suggests the `header` argument but it errors for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the first list item as the schema (second argument), and use the rest of the list as the data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data[1:], data[0])
```